# Move all apps to primary monitor when connected

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor

While my laptop is connected to a external monitor, the monitor is the primary monitor.  I often have to disconnect the monitor and all the apps jump to the laptop monitor as expected.  But when I reconnect the external monitor (and it becomes the primary monitor again), the apps all remain on laptop screen, requiring moving each one one at a time.

Is there any way to have all windows automatically or easily moved to primary monitor upon connection?

Comment: Does the external monitor and laptop have the same resolution, eg 1920x1080?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, that's right, they're both 1080p.